# How to place a object just below a image at left always at all type of screens (responsive)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Take a look at this [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/hxdrjzwr/2/)
. I want that upvote/downvote button to appear below that image at the left side. At all type of screens (desktop, mobile, tablet). I can place it at the left side, but it change it's position, when the screensize changes. How to fix this problem?

**Note:** My website will have more than 1000+ images like that and upvote/downvote buttons, so i need a specific property. I do not want to adjust the size (left, right, top) for each image.

html

```
<h3 style="position:relative;top: 40px;"><center> Welcome to ABC Site, Some text here here </center></h3>
<img id="firstpic" src="https://scontent-hkg.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/13043675_1003992606304327_2817591953882675465_n.jpg?oh=6c840d055b632ee503f498dce6662930&oe=57C7D978" alt="This image is not available, drunk.">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttons">
<input type="image" class="buttonup" id="plus" style="vertical-align:middle" src="http://i.imgur.com/jWPUjR9.png" /> <span id="count">1453</span>
<input type="image" class="buttondw" id="minus" style="vertical-align:middle" src="http://i.imgur.com/Vu6tuf9.png" />

</div>
```

CSS

```
#buttons {
margin-top: 1%;
margin-left: 50%;
 margin-right: 50%;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;

   }
    #count {
    display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0px;
     background-color: #33cc33;
   border: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
     padding: 7px;
      width: 50px;
   margin-top: 0px;
   }
.buttonup,
    .buttondw {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
   cursor: pointer;
   background: transparent;
 border: 0;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.buttonup {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/jWPUjR9.png");
}
.buttondw {
background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/Vu6tuf9.png");
}
.buttonup:hover {
 background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/SFjZ9FD.png");
 }
.buttondw:hover {
background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/aVAeO0F.png");
}

/* image mobile responsive */

 img {
    max-width: 470px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
   display: block;
    margin: 50px auto;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to wrap the buttons and image inside the same container, with the buttons wrapped inside a separate div. then make sure the button container is display block and text align left. That should help.